# How to start month's counting from a specific datetime?

Tags: python, python-datetime, python-dateutil

I'am trying to create a Deposit Calculator.

The user can have two choices, Replenishment or Partial Withdrawal per month, quarterly, annually or by choosing a specific date. Now, let's say the user want to make small replenishment starts from **2000$**, the code below works fine for **quarterly** replenishment:

```
def deposit_withdraw_relp_calc(
    formula=0.0,
    amount=0.0,
    next_date=None,
    current_date=None
):
    repl_amount = 0.0
    if next_date.month == current_date.month:
        repl_amount = amount
        formula += amount
        next_date = current_date + relativedelta.relativedelta(months=repl_period)
    else:
        repl_amount = 0.0
    return repl_amount, next_date, formula


date_start = datetime.today().date()
date_end = date_start + relativedelta.relativedelta(months=12)
next_date = date_start + relativedelta.relativedelta(months=3)

for index, dtime in enumerate(rrule(MONTHLY, dtstart=date_start, until=date_end)):

    if index == 0:
        print('\t', 'Date', '\t\t', 'Day\'s', '\t', 'Replenishment/Partial Withdrawal', '\t', '%', '\t\t', 'Deposit Amount', '\t\t', 'Capitalization')

    X = ((P * I) / DAYS_YEAR) * 30
    date = dtime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    P += X
    percents_total += X

    repl_amount, next_date, P = deposit_withdraw_relp_calc(
        formula=P,
        current_date=dtime,
        next_date=next_date,
        amount=abs(2000) if deposit_type in ['cap', 'repl'] else -abs(2000),
    )

    print('\t', date, '\t',  K, '\t\t\t', repl_amount, '\t\t\t', round(X, 2), '\t', round(P, 2), '\t\t\t', round(X, 2))
```

here are the results:

```
Date            Day's                   Replenishment/Partial Withdrawal        %               Deposit Amount                  Capitalization
2022-06-01      30                      0.0                                     1109.59         151109.59                       1109.59
2022-07-01      31                      0.0                                     1155.06         152264.65                       1155.06
2022-08-01      31                      0.0                                     1163.89         153428.53                       1163.89
2022-09-01      30                      2000                                    1134.95         156563.48                       1134.95
2022-10-01      31                      0.0                                     1196.75         157760.23                       1196.75
2022-11-01      30                      0.0                                     1166.99         158927.22                       1166.99
2022-12-01      31                      2000                                    1214.81         162142.04                       1214.81
2023-01-01      31                      0.0                                     1239.39         163381.42                       1239.39
...
```

Now let's assume that the user picked a random date let's say **2022-07-10** to start the replenishment, that means it should start on the 10th of each month starting from the 1st of the picked by user datetime, the table below shows the proof of concept:

```
Date            Day's                   Replenishment/Partial Withdrawal        %               Deposit Amount                  Capitalization
2022-06-01      30                      0.0                                     1109.59         151109.59                       1109.59

2022-07-01      31                      0.0                                     1155.06         152264.65                       1155.06
2022-07-10      31                      2000                                    1155.06         152264.65                       1155.06

2022-08-01      31                      0.0                                     1163.89         153428.53                       1163.89
2022-09-01      30                      0.0                                     1134.95         156563.48                       1134.95

2022-10-01      31                      0.0                                     1196.75         157760.23                       1196.75
2022-10-10      31                      2000                                    1196.75         157760.23                       1196.75

2022-11-01      30                      0.0                                     1166.99         158927.22                       1166.99
2022-12-01      31                      0.0                                     1214.81         162142.04                       1214.81

2023-01-01      31                      0.0                                     1239.39         163381.42                       1239.39
2023-01-10      31                      2000                                    1239.39         163381.42                       1239.39
...
```

The question is how to add that specific date into table knowing that `rrule()` is monthly not daily, in another form, what is the best way to create such a function??

Answer (score 0):

The solution was a little bit simple, I changed the loop from `MONTHLY` to `DAILY` so I can get user input date, then I need to check if timestamps of the current datetime and the user input are the same after that I can make a replenishment.

```
date_start = the_first_of_month()[1] \
    if datetime.today().date().day != 1 \
        else datetime.today().date()

date_end = date_start + relativedelta.relativedelta(months=12)

user_date = datetime.strptime('2023-01-03', '%Y-%m-%d')

for index, dtime in enumerate(rrule(DAILY, dtstart=date_start, until=date_end)):

    if index == 0:
        print('\t', 'Date', '\t\t', 'Day\'s', '\t', 'Replenishment/Partial Withdrawal', '\t', '%', '\t\t', 'Deposit Amount', '\t\t', 'Capitalization')

    if dtime.day == 1 or (dtime.day == user_date.day and dtime.timestamp() >= user_date.timestamp()):

        K = count_days_in_month(dtime.year, dtime.month)
        X = ((P * I) / DAYS_YEAR) * K
        date = dtime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        P += X
        percents_total += X

        if dtime.timestamp() >= user_date.timestamp():
            user_amount, dtime, P = deposit_withdraw_relp_calc_specific_date(
                formula=P,
                current_date=dtime,
                next_date=user_date,
                amount=abs(2000) if deposit_type in ['cap', 'repl'] else -abs(2000),
            )

        print('\t', date, '\t',  K, '\t\t\t', user_amount, '\t\t\t', round(X, 2), '\t', round(P, 2), '\t\t\t', round(X, 2))
```